# Etymology of "Dubai"

Tags: etymology, geography

I need to etymologize the city name *Dubai* (United Arab Emirates) for a project. Etymonline only lists the origins as "uncertain" and Wiktionary traces it to دُبَيّ, the Arabic term for it (pronounced *dubayy*), but goes no further. Wikipedia says the city name can possibly be traced to an Arabic word meaning "money", but provides no concrete proof of that. Uae-tour.com took a completely different angle on it and said that *Dubai* comes from the Arabic for "locust". In short, nobody agrees on its origin.

Is there any concrete research on this? What is the general conjecture among etymologists? Any help at all here would be great.

Thank you.

I already went through a period with my question about the etymology of "Djibouti"; this *is* an English word because it's listed in English dictionaries; thus there is no reason to close a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Maybe you should contact city hall.

Comment: If it is possibly from "locusts" maybe you should contact entomologists.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - That is both punny and oddly practical.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I want to go look through all your answers and upvote everything

Comment: @Unrelated Please don't do that. Votes are supposed to be based on the individual post quality, rather than the person, so [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) is strongly discouraged. If you do it, it will result in your votes being automatically reversed by the system, and potential voting restrictions in the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the etymology of 'Dubai' is not related to the *English* language, the question itself cites the Arabic origins..

Comment: @Spagirl A [similiar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/376271/etymology-of-djibouti) was closed and then re-opened. I do not know what closing will accomplish as many words in English have a non-English origin.

Comment: @Tonepoet literalist killjoy.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, that was HILARIOUS

Comment: The book [What do you know about the United Arab Emirates & Emirati Citizen ?
(By Dr.Salem Humaid)](https://books.google.ca/books?id=A12HDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&dq=dubai+word+origin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj715fZ4fDnAhUCmXIEHR-QDFkQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=dubai%20word%20origin&f=false) includes all the possible origins but the most plausible one is the diminutive of Arabic word "daba" meaning locust.

Answer (score 2):

**Dubai**

The name of this emirate and its capital **came from the word “locust” (in Arabian “dibba” and diminutive - “ dubai").** It may be connected with the fact, that it was the place of locusts breeding, that like wet soil. According to the name of the district “Bur Dubai” (“locust well”) there was a well here long time ago.

Dibbas, one more emirate city has also originated from “locust”. The other district of Dubai means just “settlement”

http://www.uae-tour.com/razdel/5/

Though, as [this article](https://www.joomag.com/magazine/dubai-june-2014/0086938001403543784?page=3) states: "none of etymological theories can be truly verified"

Comment: I already cited this...

Answer (score 0):

Du=double
Bai=bay
Geography of the area includes a double bay

As concerns Djibouti, it is : bring tea
Djibou= bring in Arabic 
Ti=tea

Comment: Any references for either of those? Both of those seems very new suggestions. I'm just wondering if there's any source that corroborates them.